# Alterar valor das tags de um XML

Tags: php, xml, php-domdocument

Eu estou com uma dificuldade. Não estou conseguindo varrer o arquivo XML e mudar os valores das tags que preciso , são elas `NOTA` e `SERIE`. Tenho que substituir essas tags com novos valores, alguém sabe como fazer isso ? Eu pesquisei , mas a estrutura do meu `XML` está me deixa com mais dificuldades. Segue os codigos.

```
public function corrigirXML() {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load("C:\BSI\INFOCLOUD\ENTRADA\\".$this->getCaminhoXmlCorrecao());

    $root = $dom->documentElement;
    $index = $root->getElementsByTagName('IndexValue');
    print_r($index);
    for ($i =0; $i<count($index); $i++) {
        $type = $index->getElementsByTagName('Label')->item($i)->textContent;
        $title = $index->getElementsByTagName('Value')->item($i)->textContent;
        echo $type." - ".$title."<br>";
    }
}
```

Estrutura XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Number>61</Number>
<PageCount>1</PageCount>
<IndexValues>
 <IndexValue>
  <Label>TIPO_DOCUMENTO</Label>
  <Value>CANHOTOS</Value>
</IndexValue>
<IndexValue>
  <Label>NOTA</Label>
  <Value>001954884</Value>
</IndexValue>
 <IndexValue>
  <Label>SERIE</Label>
  <Value>1</Value>
 </IndexValue>
</IndexValues>
</Document>
```

Comment: só uma dica, tente usar "./ "no path, desse modo fica muito mais prático para você em vez de usar o path absoluto.

Comment: Sim , não farei dessa forma. O caminho vai vim dinamicamente de outra classe, fiz assim só pra ganhar tempo mesmo e poder testar rsrs. Mas de qualquer forma obrigado.

Comment: Você quer alterar as tags ou os conteudo delas?

Comment: Os conteúdos das tags.

Comment: @MarlonCastro se alguma das respostas solucionaram teu problema, por gentileza marca a solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei uma solução. Fiz dessa forma!

```
  public function corrigirXML() {
    //Setando o DOM e versão XML
    $DOMDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $DOMDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    //Informando o caminho do XML
    $DOMDocument->load("C:\BSI\INFOCLOUD\ENTRADA\\" . $this->getCaminhoXmlCorrecao());
    //Pegando a tag para para poder fazer o foreach
    $products = $DOMDocument->getElementsByTagName('IndexValue');
    //Achando as tags filhas
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        // Guardando a tag label para a verificação
        $label = $product->getElementsByTagName('Label')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        // Se a label for iguala a nota ele muda a tag value para o valor que preciso para poder mudar o a tag no XML
        if ($label == "NOTA") {
            $product->getElementsByTagName("Value")->item(0)->nodeValue = $this->getNotaCorrecao();
        } elseif ($label == "SERIE") {
            $product->getElementsByTagName("Value")->item(0)->nodeValue = $this->getSerieCorrecao();
        }
    }
    //Salvando alterações
    echo $DOMDocument->save("C:\BSI\INFOCLOUD\ENTRADA\\" . $this->getCaminhoXmlCorrecao());
}
```

Comment: Desculpe, mas você vai explicar o código ou só colar?

Comment: Vou comenta-lo , é porque está corrido o dia.

Comment: A sua resposta e a do Marcelo praticamente são a mesma coisa, só mudou que ele usou SimpleXml e você usou DomDocument, como a pergunta é sobre a tag php-document, então do meu ponto de vista a sua resposta é a correta, mas para a resolução do problema ambas são igualmente corretas :)

Comment: É, assim que ele postou a dele eu tinha acabado de conseguir fazer rsrs. Mas eu estava lendo , e eles falaram que pra alteração de conteudo o DomDocument é melhor , mas enfim. De qualquer forma deu certo !

Comment: Não é isso que eu quis dizer, você comentou "ai a gente analisa e ver qual ficou melhor", mas tecnicamente são a mesma coisa, só mudou a API que usaram ;)

Comment: Isso mesmo! Obrigado..

Comment: Exato @Guilherme Nascimento, vi depois que postei a tag `php-domdocument`, mas como não senti a necessidade e nem foi explicado o motivo de ser apenas essa `api`, utilizei a `simpleXml`.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade eu concordo contigo, se vai apenas ler e editar coisas simples o SimpleXml é bem mais fácil, eu uso o DomDocument quando quero fazer manipulações complexas ;)

Answer (score 1):

Se quer apenas substituir os valores, percorra os nodes e faça a alteração da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Number>61</Number>
   <PageCount>1</PageCount>
   <IndexValues>
      <IndexValue>
         <Label>TIPO_DOCUMENTO</Label>
         <Value>CANHOTOS</Value>
      </IndexValue>
      <IndexValue>
         <Label>NOTA</Label>
         <Value>001954884</Value>
      </IndexValue>
      <IndexValue>
         <Label>SERIE</Label>
         <Value>1</Value>
      </IndexValue>
   </IndexValues>
</Document>
XML;

$parsedXml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach($parsedXml->IndexValues->IndexValue as $item)
{
    if($item->Label == 'NOTA'){
        $item->Value = 'xxxxxx';
    }

    if($item->Label == 'SERIE'){
        $item->Value = 'ABC123';
    }
}

$parsedXml->asXML("newdoc.xml");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Marcelo. Porém agora mesmo eu conseguir solucionar também , vou postar minha resposta também ai a gente analisa e ver qual ficou melhor e encerramos o tópico.